# Alternatives to "that"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence-patterns

I am required to use: The fact `that`...., One of the major advantage is `that`...., A key problem with this definition is `that`....,The observation `that`...., The reason why it accounted for x is `that`.....

As you can see all of the above sentences have the word `that`. I have used these sentences and a lot more sentences that have `that` in them, in a report. I feel it would be better not to use the word `that` these many times. Can these sentences be re framed without the word `that`? By any chance is there a general solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean, “You are required to use”?

Comment: There's almost always a way to reword to avoid "that", but one needs to see a complete sentence to suggest the most idiomatic way.

Comment: In many cases, *that* can simply be omitted and have the meaning of the sentence remain. (Occasionally, you can't just remove it, but have to rephrase the sentence.) In those cases, its use is optional. There are *some* instances where *that* actually is required, syntactically, but not that many. And even there, it's probably possible to rephrase the surrounding text to remove it too.

Comment: Try reordering some of your sentences:  “One of the major advantages is that...”  becomes “... Is one of the major advantages.”  “... Is a key problem with this definition.” etc